# C++ cannot run after software update

Tags: c++

So, I just started learning C++ as my first programming language. Yesterday, it was fine and today I decided to update my mac os to the latest version (Big Sur) and suddenly when I want to run my C++ code again it doesn't want to run and give some errors. Any help or suggestion, please?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name = "Jason";

    cout << name;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't show images of text, least of all code. Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the code into it, and then copy the output from the "Output" tab into the question as well.

Comment: To begin with, `std::string` is found in `#include <string>`.

Comment: Do you get the same errors if you compile? Depending on what toolchain you're using, you might need to update that and/or the VS Code configuration.

Comment: This could be because of changes in libstdc++. See in https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html: "Reduced header dependencies, leading to faster compilation for some code".

Comment: I'm guessing what you have going on here is actually a problem with vscode, rather than C++/OSX.  Were I to speculate, I'd say that the compiler and headers that vscode is looking at no longer exist (in the location that they used to be).


First confirm that you've got the compiler (xcode/apple clang?) installed, then double check those c_cpp_properties and settings.json files, and potentially delete them at let vscode recreate them.  Have you confirmed that you can compile the code outside of vscode?

Comment: Oh, okay I'll copy it next time. This is my first time using stackoverflow. and update: when i check wether i have gcc installed on terminal, it shows that i have not downloaded it. for some reason it got deleted i think after i update my software. thakyou btw for your replies!

Comment: Install [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) on your computer (perhaps as part of [Debian](http://debian.org/)...) and run it as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Your code will give warnings and error messages. Read [documentation of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) and some recent C++ standard (e.g. [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or better) and see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)...

Comment: yes, i have install GCC again and i can already run my code again, thankyou

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!